# Why are du some options not available

Tags: disk-usage, busybox

I have been using bash on my Synology NAS (which runs BusyBox). I recently needed to reinstall the OS. Now a script I have that uses du to generate a file containing folder sizes fails because du now has fewer options. i.e.

```
du -hc --max-depth=1 --exclude=deleted --exclude=README.txt --exclude=#recycle /path/to/event_media/* >> /path/to/media_files_list.txt
```

gives me:

```
du: unrecognized option '--max-depth=1'
```

So when I...

```
du --help
```

I get..

```
BusyBox v1.16.1 (2014-05-29 11:29:56 CST) multi-call binary.

Usage: du [-aHLdclsxhmk] [FILE]...

Summarize disk space used for each FILE and/or directory.
Disk space is printed in units of 1024 bytes.


Options:

    -a      Show file sizes too
    -L      Follow all symlinks
    -H      Follow symlinks on command line
    -d N    Limit output to directories (and files with -a) of depth < N
    -c      Show grand total
    -l      Count sizes many times if hard linked
    -s      Display only a total for each argument
    -x      Skip directories on different filesystems
    -h      Sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 243M 2G )
    -m      Sizes in megabytes
    -k      Sizes in kilobytes (default)
```

There is a reduced set of options.

Can anyone please help me understand what has changed and how to set it up to regain access to the full set of options such as max-depth and exclude?

Comment: BusyBox has been written with size-optimization and limited resources in mind. Synology has include or exclude commands at the compile time to customize for their embedded systems. I love Synology NAS devices. they are great for home and SB

Comment: I believe you can replace `--max-depth = 1` with `-d 1`

Comment: Thank you @Celada - yes that works well for restricting the directory level. I'm keen also to exclude the other directories so I don't have to modify my scripts to check for them. Any ideas on what I was using originally with the first install? Am I only using ash and have some kind of path problem that prevents the full bash somehow? (If I login to SSH and enter /opt/bin/bash I get the same help file for du)

Answer (score 3):

The option you're trying to use is available in the [GNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU) version of `du` (from the [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html) package), which is what you'll find on non-embedded Linux systems. Your NAS provides the [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) version, which is what you'll usually find on embedded systems. BusyBox utilities are smaller (less disk space, less RAM) but have fewer features.

You'll need to either install GNU coreutils or adapt your script to what is available on your system. A Google search suggests that you can install GNU coreutils [through ipkg](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/A_short_list_of_the_more_useful_900+_ipkg_packages).

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was wanting to know.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make the top answer clearer on this point.

You can still use `max-depth=#` on busybox `du` but you just need to change to

```bash
du --max-depth=#
# Becomes
du -d #
```

And for the exclude folders you can just there isn't a argument but you can just select the folders you do want

```bash
du --exclude folder3
# Becomes
du folder1 folder2 folder4
```